# Counting number of chars in string and convert it to int

Tags: c++

I'm a bit of a C++ noob. I'm working on this program that requires my program to count how many characters are in a word. I've tried using `strlen()`, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

I also need the number that's printed from `strlen()` to be converted to an int.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
char str[64];
cin >> str;
cout << "strlen: " << strlen(str) << endl;
cout << "sizeof: " << sizeof(str) << endl;
```

Comment: If you are learning C++, don't use arrays of char - use std::string.

Answer (score 1):

in

```
     cout << "strlen: " << strlen(str) << endl;
     cout << "sizeof: " << sizeof(str) << endl;
```

*strlen* return the number of characters before the final null character, so the result depends on the contents of *str*, this can be 0 if `str[0] == 0`

*sizeof* return the size, here 64, independently of the contents. The unit of *sizeof* is the *char*, by definition *sizeof(char)* is 1

this is the same in C++ and C

---

> need the number that's printed from strlen to be converted to an int.

Example from your code :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  char str[64];

  if (cin>>str) {
    cout << "strlen: " << strlen(str) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof: " << sizeof(str) << endl;

    errno = 0;

    char * endptr;
    long int v = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);

    if ((endptr != str) && (errno == 0))
      cout << "value :" << v << endl;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ ./a.out
123
strlen: 3
sizeof: 64
value :123
```

---

However rather than to use C array you can use *std::string* as subjected in remarks, for instance :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string str;

  if (cin>>str) {
    cout << "len: " << str.length() << endl;

    istringstream is(str);
    long v;

    if (is >> v)
      cout << "value :" << v << endl;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/d $ ./a.out
123
len: 3
value :123
```

Note that it is of course shorter to directly read the number rather than first read a string